# Chapter names for two opposite things

Tags: word-choice, titles

I'm having five different algorithms about which I have to write a report. First, I analyze each algorithm on its own and then I compare the algorithms.

My problem now is that I need two section names for both things, i.e. for analyzing each algorithm on its own and for comparing the algorithms.

I'm thinking of something like "Within Algorithm Comparison" and "Between Algorithm Comparison" but this does not sound very correct.

Does somebody have other suggestions?

Comment: You could say "algorithm-specific analysis" and "inter-algorithm comparison".

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sounds good as a start. Is the hyphen neccessary?

Comment: Yes, the hyphen is necessary.

Comment: What do you think about  "inter-algorithm analysis" and  "intra-algorithm analysis"?

Comment: "intra" implies that you are looking at things **inside** the  algorithm, but you're not - you're looking at the algorithm itself.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'm looking at different parameter settings for the algoirthm, for example. Could this not be "inside"? The parameters are inside the algorithm as part of the implementation.

Comment: @MaxWilliams just one last thing. In a section I would like to present the chosen parameter values (which I have fixed for an experiment). How would you name such a section? Something like "Parameter Values" or "Chosen Parameter Values" sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: I'd call it "Example parameters" perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the spirit of keeping the writing simple, you can go with:

> - Analysis of algorithms
> - Comparison of algorithms

Under the 'Analysis' section, you can examine each algorithm in the required amount of detail. Once you have explained all the algorithms, use the 'Comparison' section to point out similarities and differences between them.

You can make the title a bit more specific by referring to the process that the algorithm does. As an example, if the algorithm refers to Machine Learning, you can write it as:

> - Analysis of Machine Learning algorithms
> - Comparison of Machine Learning algorithms